# Mongodb moq unit test mock mongo collection issue

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to access the IMongoCollection.Database but i am getting null from the unit test, can someone please help me identify this issue?

```
[Fact] 
public async void
        SaveEmployee_Should_Upsert_The_Employee()
 
var mockDbService = new Mock<IDatabaseService>();
        
 var employeeMockCollection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<Employee>>();

   mockDbService
                .Setup(service => service.GetCollection('Employee'))
                .Returns(employeeMockCollection.Object);
    

collectionMock
                .Setup(
                    collection => collection.UpdateOneAsync(
                        It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<TDbEntity>>(),
                        It.IsAny<UpdateDefinition<TDbEntity>>(),
                        It.IsAny<UpdateOptions>(),
                        CancellationToken.None
                    )
                )
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(expectedReturn));

    await SaveEmployee(employeeMockCollection.Object);

}

 public void SaveEmployee(IMongoCollection<Employee> collection)

 {
      var session=collection
                .Database
                .Client
                .StartSessionAsync(new ClientSessionOptions());
    //collection.Database is null

 }
```

here is the screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By this line:

```
var employeeMockCollection = new Mock<IMongoCollection<Employee>>();
```

you only say that when you call `IMongoCollection<Employee>` methods/props of this mocked instance, all methods/props will return default values ie given that you didn't call any `Setup` for this collection, all underlying methods and properties will return `null`.

**But**, it's in general a bad idea to mock code that you don't own.